# Python opencv wait for camera to be free

Tags: django, opencv, celery

My idea is using a Raspberry Pi for streaming video, for which Django will do the heavy lifting. In **another process**, I will also run some Celery workers, which capture a picture from the same camera every 5th seconds and send the picture to the public server.

The Django server will be started with `python manage.py runserver`

The Celery workers will be started with `celery -A videoclient worker -l info -B --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler`

Following is the code to access the camera. Since there is only one camera and two independent processes want to access it, how can I make the line `self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` wait for the camera to be free instead of throwing an exception? For my requirement a high latency is acceptable.

Camera code

```
import cv2


class VideoCamera(object):
    def get_frame(self):
        try:
            self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
            success, image = self.video.read()
            self.video.release()
            ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
            return jpeg.tobytes()
        finally:
            self.video.release()


video_camera = VideoCamera()


def gen(camera):
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')
```

Streaming on local browser:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse
from django.urls import path

from videoclient.camera import video_camera, gen

urlpatterns = [
    path('monitor/', lambda r: StreamingHttpResponse(gen(video_camera),
                                                     content_type='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

]

Celery:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery, shared_task
from django.conf import settings
from videoclient.camera import video_camera

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'videoclient.settings')

app = Celery('videoclient')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')

app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))

@shared_task
def uploadimage():
    image = video_camera.get_frame()
    # Upload the image to server
```

Comment: Make another process, which will be the only one reponsible for accessing and controlling the pysical camera. This process can the provide the acquired images to multiple client processes using some form of IPC.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you have 2 processes running get_frame(), which causes the camera to take a photo. If two of them call the camera at the same time, it can cause an error.

Instead, try this approach:

1) In the main thread, have the camera taking photos on a loop, and updating a variable, self.latestFrame, with the latest frame.

2) Any process that wants to get the latest frame gets the self.latestFrame variable, **without** accessing the camera.

In other words, you only have one camera object and one process taking photos. That process updates a variable, which any other process can access without causing issues.

Comment: Well, since we are talking about two processes and not two threads, your method will sadly not work.